# My Android app cant communicate with my server...in my computer

Tags: android, spring

I have an app made in Android that communicates with a server, in my computer. I moved from another home to here where I am recently: new router, etc, so I need to know my new ip. Im on windows 7, so I go to cmd and type ipconfig. In IPv4 address it says "10.0.0.107". In my strings.xml, in the Android app,  have somthing like that:

```
<string name="host">http://10.0.0.107</string
```

In my former home, it said `http://192.168.1.3`, which looks better to me, but my ipconfig says 10.0.0.107, so I have to trust it.

I try to log in my app (which worked perfectly in my former home). The url where Im trying to connect is:

```
http://10.0.0.107:8080/myappname/usuario/login
```

Im using Spring for the server side. This is the method that should deal with log in:

```
@RequestMapping("/usuario/login")
    @ResponseBody
    public String login(@RequestParam("user")String username, @RequestParam ("pass") String password){
        System.out.println("Login method called");
//stuff
}
```

That sysout is not called.

I am receiving this, in the device:

```
    07-24 21:17:25.320: I/LOGIN(9712): Url de logueo: http://10.0.0.107:8080/appark/usuario/login
07-24 21:17:25.370: I/LOGIN(9712): Respuesta del server: <html><head><title>VMwarevFabrictcRuntime2.9.2.RELEASE/7.0.39.B.RELEASE-InformedeError</title><style><!--H1{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}H2{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}H3{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;}BODY{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}B{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;}P{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A{color:black;}A.name{color:black;}HR{color:#525D76;}--></style></head><body><h1>EstadoHTTP404-/appark/usuario/login</h1><HRsize="1"noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b>Informedeestado</p><p><b>mensaje</b><u>/appark/usuario/login</u></p><p><b>descripción</b><u>Elrecursorequeridonoestádisponible.</u></p><HRsize="1"noshade="noshade"><h3>VMwarevFabrictcRuntime2.9.2.RELEASE/7.0.39.B.RELEASE</h3></body></html>
```

That worked perfectly in my former home. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: What is the goal of your question? I don't see it

Comment: The server must return a string to the device, but it returns a 404 page.

Comment: It looks like the petition is not arriving to the server.

Comment: At first - try to check your server response via browser on your android device. Just type a necessary url (ip) and take a look what server does responding

Comment: I solved it already...was a port problem, don't know why, but the server was using 8081 instead of 8080. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's my pleasure. Don't forget to close this question - mark it as solved. Good luck!

Comment: No answers, so I will write an answer and will mark it as answered, when I am able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... my server was using 8081 port instead of 8080.